# Read R console with RInside

Tags: c++, r, qt, rcpp, rinside

I'm using Rcpp and RInside to run some commands into R.
I've made a personal GUI (in Qt) which sends commands, and I would like to recover the result in std::string format.

Example :

> $ 1 + 1

The result is :

> [1] 2

And I want to have this string :

> "[1] 2"

I already check string cast with "as" and "as_string", but the cast is invalid cause of intern return type in R.

Is it possible to read R console output or something else ?

EDIT:

```
void RppMainWindow::runLineOnScriptCursor() {
    std::string line = script->getCodeEditor()->lineOnCursor();
    if ( line.empty() || line == INVALID ) {
        return;
    }
    RCommand cmd (script->getConsoleViewer(), r);
    cmd.execute(line);
}

void RCommand::execute(std::string commande) {
    std::string res = executeOnR(commande);
    viewer->addEntry(commande, res);
}

void ConsoleViewer::addEntry(std::string command, std::string result) {
    this->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End);

    QTextCharFormat format;
    format.setFontWeight(QFont::DemiBold);
    format.setForeground(QBrush(QColor("red")));
    this->mergeCurrentCharFormat(format);
    std::string tmp = "> " + command + "\n";
    this->insertPlainText(QString(tmp.c_str()));


    this->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End);

    format.setFontWeight(QFont::Normal);
    format.setForeground(QBrush(QColor("blue")));
    this->mergeCurrentCharFormat(format);
    if ( ! result.empty() ) {
        result += "\n";
    }
    this->insertPlainText(QString(result.c_str()));
}
```

ConsoleViewer allow to display a basic R console like this

> $ R command
>
> *return if needed*

Comment: Presumably your project consists of several files as it is a Qt GUI application, but could you include the relevant sections of code that handle this command IO?

Comment: I've made it, thanks for your answer. I hope you could help me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want

> "[1] 2"

you need to setup a formatting routine at your end that receives the `2` from RInside and prepends `[1]` (and ditto for the other lines).  This is just what `print()` does in R:

```
edd@max:~$ R --slave -e 'print(1+1)'
[1] 2
edd@max:~$ R --slave -e 'cat(1+1, "\n")'
2 
edd@max:~$
```

I actually prefer `cat()` on my results but `print()` can be emulated too.

Comment: 1+1 return 2, but on R console display "[1] 2", it's true ?

Comment: *Because of the way R (as an interactive environment) prints*.  If you call `int R.parseEvalQ("1+1")` you get an `int` with the value of 2.

Comment: So i need some functions to detect and cast each type! Thanks :)

Comment: No you don't.  You need to sit down and read and compiled and experiment with a bunch of the existing examples.  You are confused about absolute pre-beginners issues, and I am afraid you are not using your time efficiently but firing off one-liners here.  Do some background reading, learn about Rcpp, run examples.